# Should I use dashes or commas?

Tags: punctuation

Which sentence is correct?

1- I worked on, and helped my friend with, many projects.

2- I worked on -and helped my friend with- many projects.

I used to use commas like the first example, but now I'm leaning towards the second one.

Comment: A picky point: you've got hyphens abutted to the following word where you need em-dashes that are space-separated.

Comment: You mean like: I worked on -- and helped my friend with -- many projects.

Comment: -- two hyphens; – en dash; — em dash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is largely going to depend on where this text is to be written - some publishers will have a style-guide that tells you which they expect, though I think commas will be more common. Functionally, both your examples are interchangeable, though it is more normal in my experience to have a space on either side of the dash, as you will see in my first line.

(I've also never seen a dash used to follow a bullet-point, the commonest usage is:  `1.`  or  `(2)` and this confused me for a second when reading your question! )

Comment: Thank you for the information on bullet-points. Regarding the dash usage, should I use dashes or em-dashes as shin suggested?

Comment: Technically, the minus sign, the hyphen, the en-dash and the em-dash are all different glyphs, but in general usage very few people know which is which, and some word processors will change one into another without warning. I'm not sure what 'shin' is suggesting - I don't see a comment with that name.